# How can you make a rake task that makes changes in multiple environments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a rake task that I use to populate my development database.  When it is done I would like it to also reset the test database, but I can't figure out the syntax.  I need something like this:

```
namespace :db do
  task populate: :environment do
    Rake::Task["db:reset"].execute
    Rake::Task["db:reset"].execute RAILS_ENV=test
    # Add lots of data to the :environment database
  end
end
```

This lets me run `rake db:populate` to populate my development database using the latest schema as well as reset the test database.

Answer (score 0):

The task `db:test:clone_structure` will reset the test database schema to match the development database schema

```
namespace :db do
  task populate: :environment do
    Rake::Task["db:reset"].execute
    Rake::Task["db:test:clone_structure"].execute
    # Add lots of data to the :environment database
  end
end
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesnt work for some reason. The DB is just empty, no tables at all.